# Pros and Cons of Core isolation and memory integrity in Windows 11

Tags: virtualization, windows-11, hardware-virtualization, virtualization-based-security

Almost the same question has already been asked for Windows 10: [What is Windows 10's core isolation memory integrity setting, and what does it do?](https://superuser.com/q/1325483/939073) 4 years ago and a good answer has been provided under this link: https://www.howtogeek.com/357757/what-are-core-isolation-and-memory-integrity-in-windows-10/.

Does the same hold for Windows 11 in the year 2022? (I have the feeling that Windows is pushing more for it recently.)

Is it still true that virtual machines are not compatible with memory integrity under Windows 11? In general the compatibility issues with memory integrity have probably rather become less than more?

I guess the performance loss will still be at least as low in Windows 11 as it was in Windows 10 according to https://superuser.com/a/1325680/939073?

In https://superuser.com/a/1325680/939073 it was mentioned that the security benefits of  memory integrity were not too big under Windows 10. Has the situation changed in the last years?

Comment: It’s literally the same feature. “Is it still true that virtual machines are not compatible with memory integrity under Windows 11?” - This hasn’t been the case since Windows 10 21H1

Comment: @Ramhound If I understood you correctly the situation is quite different now than in the year 2018 as the main incompatibility issue as been resolved since Windows 10 21H1? Then there are no important reasons left to keep memory integrity turned off nowadays?